# Domain registrar that doesn't encourage domain 'speculation'

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

Dealing with domain 'speculators' has been getting me down recently. Then I noticed my current registrar, name.com, have some deal with a domain auction company to list "premium" domains on their website; it may seem petty, but I don't want to support this kind of venture in any way.

Are there any good registrars out there who don't list 'aftermarket' domains? I don't need much in the way of features, but a nice clean interface is always nice.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I do most of my domain registration and hosting through sustainablehosting.com. They are slightly more expensive then the big boys, but I'm supporting a small, environmentally friendly company, and they don't spam me with anything. To the best of my knowledge, they don't participate in any "speculative" or "aftermarketin" shenanigans.